# gsub to replace and reorder string

Tags: regex, string, r

I would like to replace multiple instances of the following:

```
--- \n\n ## Some Text
```

With:

```
Some Text \n ======================== \n\n
```

I can't figure out the right combination of regex to do so.

Help! It's making me crazy!

Bonus: show me how to do it in the opposite direction!

Comment: Can you show the "wrong combination of regex" that you have tried so far? Would you consider using something other than `r`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using capturing group:

```
> s <- "--- \n\n ## Some Text\n\n--- \n\n ## Another Text"
> gsub("---\\s*\n\n\\s*##\\s*(.+)", "\\1 \n ======== \n\n", s, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Some Text \n ======== \n\n\n\nAnother Text \n ======== \n\n"
```

Comment: Why do some of your `\n` have a double backslash when others don't?

Comment: @Floris, I didn't need to escape `\n`. I updated the code. Thank you for comment.

Comment: now I understand, and can up vote, your solution. :-)